# How do I update the Lotus Notes Document?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

1. For some enhancing reason, I have added some new fields in my form. It is having default value.
2. But the existing document is not getting updated with the new fields.
3. I am having a thousands of documents. I can not open, Edit and save. I tried to save the document from backend. I can not believe, that was also not working.
4. Is their anyway for updating documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view action button that executes this command:

[@Command[ToolsRefreshAllDocs])](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TOOLSREFRESHALLDOCS.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using backend classes, you need call `notesDocument.ComputeWithForm( False, False )` before saving document.